# C++ Strange error, "no conversion from 'int' to 'int (__cdecl *)(float,float)'"

Tags: c++

First of all this is my first question on stackoverflow. I'm trying to complete a homework assignment but I don't know what I might be doing wrong.

I get an error, "no conversion from 'int' to 'int (__cdecl *)(float,float)'" when I try to run a function for the second time. The function is supposed to return either 0, -1, or +1, and that's used in a if/else statement.

Here's the chunk of code I'm referring to...

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;


////this function returns a -1 if the left pan has a weight more than the right, a 0 if the weights of the two pans are equal, and a +1 if the right pan has a greater weight than the left
int weigh(float leftpan, float rightpan)
{
 //compare the pan weights, return value
}


float findOddRock(float r1, float r2, float r3, float r4, float r5, float r6, float r7)
{
    //first weigh
    float first_leftpan = r1 + r2;
    float first_rightpan = r3 + r4;

    weigh(first_leftpan, first_rightpan);
    if(weigh == 0){
        cout << "this program is working so far";
        float second_leftpan = r5; //this brings up an error for some reason
        float second_rightpan = r6;
        weigh(second_leftpan, second_rightpan);


//here's where I get the error, no conversion from 'int' to 'int (__cdecl *)(float,float)'
        if(weigh == 0){   //be careful here, changed from second_weigh to weigh
            float third_leftpan = r5; 
            float third_rightpan = r7;
            weigh(third_leftpan, third_rightpan);
 }

//
int main()
{
 //find the light rock
 findOddRock(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to compare the return value of the function to `0`:

```
 weigh(first_leftpan, first_rightpan);
    if(weigh == 0){
```

try doing:

```
if(weigh(first_leftpan, first_rightpan) == 0){
```

Also the function `weight` is not returning anything..fix that.

And if you are trying to compare two floats with `==` be warned about the floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: I didn't put the whole weigh function in there, just to be concise, but I do have it set up to return values.

edit: So what's up with the whole thing about floating point inaccuracies?

Comment: @Charli you are comparing a float to an int. This means that anything after the decimal point is not considered in the comparison. What you want to do is compare a float variable to a floating pt number.

Comment: How do I change the function so that it DOES return something? I want to return strings just saying which rock is odd and what weight it is.

Comment: @Reno When you compare a float and an integer, the integer is promoted to float. There is no inaccuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone above is correct, but let's talk about what the error message is telling you.

`weigh` is a function that takes two `float`s and returns an `int`, as you already know.

So. the value you get from calling `weigh` is an `int`.  So your basic idea is correct.

Hwever, when you wrote `if(weigh == 0)`, you left off an essential part, the `()`.  That's the syntax in C/C++ for calling a function.  `weigh`, then is just the name of the function, which is the same as its "address".  The full name of functions in C/C++ include the arguments, so the full name of the function is really

- a C-style function `_cdecl`
- returning an `int`
- taking two arguments `(float, float)`

and the symbol `weigh` is the *address* of that function, which for complicated reasons I imagine you haven't seen yet, makes the full type of `weigh` into `int(_cdecl*)(float,float)`.

So what the error message is saying is "an integer comparison should be between two `int`s, but what you gave me is an `int` and the address of a function with two float arguments *returning* an `int`.  Which I'm too dumb to understand."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if(weigh == 0)
```

You're trying to compare the function `weigh` to zero, rather than comparing a variable containing the return value.

Comment: I took the advice, and now the program runs, but the findOddRock doesn't return any of the strings I included. What is wrong with the function that's keeping it from returning any of the strings?

Answer (score 0):

whats up with this :

```
if(weigh == 0)
```

why are you comparing a function to 0 ?

I think you really meant to do was

```
if(0 == weigh( blah, blah ))
```

*Next to solve your logic problems*

You are trying to find the stone with the least weight. 
What you should be using is sorting. Since you are new to this C thingy read [this article](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c10.htm)

Create a function that sorts an array of float. The lowest element (or 1st element in an ascending array) is the odd stone.

Answer (score 0):

with `if (weigh == 0)`
you are trying to compare the address of a function (name of the function as an lvalue) to zero

`weigh == 0` will never be true, as you have defined weigh.

I believe this is what you want:

```
int result = weigh(first_leftpan, first_rightpan)
if ( result == 0)
```

Comment: That is not an address of a function. `int (* func)(float, float) = weigh;` is an address of a function.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison

```
(weigh == 0)
```

is comparing a function pointer to an integer. The reason the error is showing up on the second instance instead of the first is an artifact of your compiler. I'm fairly certain if you comment out the line giving you the error you will get a similar error on the first. (though some compilers may implicitly convert 0 to a pointer and allow the comparison... in which case you may be seeing the error due to missing closing brackets perhaps?)

Regardless, it looks like you are wanting to compare the result of the call to weigh in which case you should capture the return value and use it in your comparison.

```
int ret = weigh(first_leftpan, first_rightpan);
if(ret == 0){
...
```